# helm configuration for added repositories

Tags: kubernetes-helm

using [helm](https://github.com/helm/helm) (version 3), after a [repository was added](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_repo_add/) and it is shown when [listing the repository](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_repo_list/), and  each repository can be [updated](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_repo_update/) at any time.

i want to share my `helm repo list` with others.

1. is there a way to do it using some file which helm honors?
2. if not, how do i find the path where helm keeps track which repositories (and their version) were added?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
helm repo list -o json > repo.json
```